# MongoDB - How to find and update elements in a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

Here is the collection:

```
db.employees.insertMany([
   {
    "data": {
      "category": [
        {
          "name": "HELLO",
          "subcategory": [
            "EDUCATION",
            "ART",
            
          ]
        },
         {
          "name": "HELLO",
          "subcategory": [
            "GG",
            "ART",
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "HELLO",
          "subcategory": [
            "EDUCATION",
            "SHORE",
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "category": [
        {
          "name": "HELLO",
          "subcategory": [
            "EDUCATION",
            "HELLO",
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "category": [
        {
          "name": "HELLO",
          "subcategory": [
            "GG",
            "ART",
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

What I want is to locate the elements in 'category' with a 'subcategory' that contains 'EDUCATION' and replace 'EDUCATION' with another string, let's say 'SPORTS'.

I tried a couple of commands but nothing really did the job:

```
db.employees.updateMany({
  "data.category.subcategory": "EDUCATION"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "data.category.$": {
      "subcategory": "SPORTS"
    }
  }
})
```

What I saw is that it doesn't update the element by replacing it and it doesn't replace every element that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think that [MongoDB Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) fulfills your scenario.

1. `$set` - Set `data.category` value.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in `data.category` and return an array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current document with the document with `subcategory` field from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1 `$map` - Iterate each value from the `subcategory` array. With `$cond` to replace the word `EDUCATION` with `SPORTS` if fulfilled, else use existing value (`$$this`).

```
db.employees.updateMany({
  "data.category.subcategory": "EDUCATION"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "data.category": {
        $map: {
          input: "$data.category",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                subcategory: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.subcategory",
                    in: {
                      $cond: {
                        if: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this",
                            "EDUCATION"
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "SPORTS",
                        else: "$$this"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jn5iqdEOZdk)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it using `"arrayFilters"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "data.category.subcategory": "EDUCATION"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "data.category.$[].subcategory.$[elem]": "SPORTS"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    { "elem": "EDUCATION" }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CRqkTuar1dF).